# How to run utserver on Debian Wheezy 7.1?

Tags: debian, utorrent, openssl, debian-wheezy

On Debian Whezy 7.1, after installing OpenSSL as http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/advanced/installing-openssl-098-on-debian-7-wheezy directs, I cant run utserver, where on Squeeze it was running out of box.

Getting error like the file would not exist. Internet says it maybe crashes silenty but than no logs are provided:

```
$ ./utserver
bash: ./utserver: No such file or directory
```

How to run it?

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step ? It's for Ubuntu, but it should make no difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: What does that mean? What does it do? How will that solve the issue?

Comment: Giving context or explanation would be handy and is required, but minusing the answer itself is little to harash isin't it?